# flutter carousel slider start from specific position

Tags: flutter

I want to start carousel slider from a specific index. My carousel slider widget takes a `props` object which has below properties:

```
class Props {
  List<String> strings;
  int index;

  Props({
    required this.index,
    required this.strings,
  });
}
```

And my carousel slider is as:

```
    return CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        ...
      ),
      carouselController: controller,
      items: widget.props.strings.map(
        (item) {
          ..some widget
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
```

Everything is all good except I want to start the carousel from `widget.props.index`. So rather than starting from index 0 of `List<String>` I can start from index 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `initialPage` field by setting the `options`.

```dart
CarouselSlider(
  // ...
  options: CarouselOptions(
    initialPage: 2,
  ),
),
```